# DACPAC Deploy via c# fails due to missing user

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote a small tool that uploads a .bak file to a local SQL instance and then retrieves a DACPAC from the newly created database. Then the DACPAC is deployed to another SQL instance, which is not on the same machine.

All these steps are done in C# via Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo and Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac. However, the last step (deploying to remote server) fails, saying that the process could not create a user. I can live with dropping that user, however i don't want to manually modify the dacpac file or the database. I tried configuring the Deploy process in order to skip the user, but it doesn't work.

This is my code for the deploy:

```
var remoteService = new DacServices(targetConnection);
try
{
    var package = DacPackage.Load(file.FullName);
    var settings = new DacDeployOptions();
    settings.IgnoreUserSettingsObjects = true;
    remoteService.Deploy(package, targetName, false, settings);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    DeleteDb(targetName, targetConnection);
}
```

On execution, following error message is shown (freely translated, couldn't find this error or similar on Google so I don't know the actual English translation)

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: The Windows NT user or group '[XYZ]' was not found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by deleting all additional non-System users from the source database before extracting the dacPackage.